# Orientation of Magnetic Dipoles

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

Does a magnetic dipole (in a permanent magnet) tend to align with the B-field or with the H-field?

The current loop (Ampère) model of the magnetic dipole suggests the former, while the magnetic-monopole (Gilbert) model suggests the latter.

Answer (score 1):

(A) If you put a B-field in free space and a small magnet in the field, it rotates so that the magnetic moment is parallel to the B-field (U=-m⋅B, so potential energy is minimized when m and B are parallel).

(B) Inside a bar magnet, the B-field points parallel to the m's inside the magnet, while the H-field points in the opposite direction to the m's.

(If the bar magnet is a very very long, narrow cylinder, polarized along its axis, then the H field is almost 0, so $B/\mu_0$ is almost equal to M.)

Based on (A) and (B), you might think that the magnetic field tends to stabilize a bar magnet, but in reality it's the exact opposite -- they call it a "demagnetizing field" for a reason. The magnetic field wants to flip the magnets around and stop the alignment of magnetic moments. The bar magnet maintains its magnetization *despite* its own magnetic field, rather than because of it. (The more important factor is that the bar magnet wants to minimize electron kinetic energy, which is related to spin-alignment via the Pauli exclusion principle.) The demagnetizing field is the main reason domains form in magnets.

Most magnetism is associated with electron spins. These are true intrinsic point dipoles: Neither current loops nor magnetic-monopole-pairs. It turns out that H is almost always more helpful than B for understanding the behavior of magnetic materials, but I don't think there's any fundamental reason for that, it's just the result when you work everything out very carefully.

Answer (score -1):

$$\vec{H}=\frac{\vec{B}}{\mu_0}-\vec{M}$$
And since dipole moment is always colinear with itself, aligning with B-field is equivalent to aligning with H-field.